# Как можно компактно написать поиск минимума в зубчатом массиве?

Tags: c#

Есть массив `arr`, элементы которого являются массивами `DateTime[]`.

Другими словами `arr` хранит определенное количество массивов `DateTime[]`, есть `index` - интекс текущего элемента, он применяется ко всем массивам.

Нужно найти самую раннюю дату среди `index+1` элементов во всех массивах `DateTime[]`. Массивы разных размерностей, и в одном или некоторых может не оказаться `index+1` элемента.

```
DateTime[][] arr = new DateTime[3][];
arr[0] = new DateTime[3];
arr[1] = new DateTime[2];
arr[2] = new DateTime[4];
int index = 0;
int arrIndexInit = 0; //индекс первого массива у которого есть index+1 элемент
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    if(index + 1 < arr[i].Length)
    {
        arrIndexInit = i;
        break;
    }
}
DateTime nextEarliestDate = arr[arrIndexInit][index + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) //проходим по всем массивам, и сравниваем их дату с минимальной
{
    if (index + 1 < arr[i].Length) //если в масиве есть index+1 элемент
    {
        if (DateTime.Compare(arr[i][index + 1], nextEarliestDate) < 0)
        {
            nextEarliestDate = arr[i][index + 1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `arr.OrderBy(x => x).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: `arr.SelectMany(x => x).Min()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В LINQ уже есть метод находящий минимальное число:

```
var numbers = new List<int> { 1, 8, 3, 2 };

int minNumber = numbers.Min();
```

еще можно взять метод minBy для нахождения минимального числа по переменной или проперте у обьектов - пример реализации в [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs)

Вообще для обьединения двух списков поиндексно существует такая вещь как Zip. Zip поддерживающий 3 массива есть начиная с .net 6

```
IEnumerable<(int a1, int a2, int a3)> zip = arr1.Zip(arr2, arr3);
```

после чего применить Min на каждом наборе результатов и получить минимальную дату по всем 3м спискам сравнива даты в рамках одного индекса по всех массивах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Ну а если необходимо один минимум из всех (а не поиндексный минимум) - то необходимо воспользоваться flatMap (в шарпе SelectMany) для того что бы сделать из N массивов (вложенных в один массив) в один последовательный массив значених всех 3х массивов, после чего уже находим минимум по этому массиву.

```
var min = arrayOfArrays.SelectMany(x => x).Min()
```